# Angular5 + Jquery Datatable + Liferay 7.1 unable to instantiate datatable

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, liferay-7

I am creating a portlet on Liferay 7.1 generated using blade-cli and npm-angular template. As per my requirement, the following combination seems perfect:

Angular + JQuery Datatable (on Liferay 7.1 platform).

I followed the code as per the following repo:
https://github.com/liorchamla/angular-datatables-from-scratch

I am able to build and deploy the project successfully, but then when I am trying to register datatable() to the jquery table object I am getting the following error in the chrome devtools, but I can see the data on HTML table (normal HTML table no datatable features):

```
core.umd.js:1487 ERROR TypeError: table.DataTable is not a function
at SafeSubscriber._next (app.component.ts:32)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:258)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:208)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:139)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:83)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.ts:96)
at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.ts:154)
```

I validated the following points:

1. The same code works fine on a stand-alone angular code (without Liferay) created using angular-cli.
2. When debugging the code on Liferay server, I see that I have the jquery object when calling $("table") in the below snippet, but the code fails with the above error when calling datatable() on the same object.

====

```
ngOnInit(){
this.http.get('https://5a5a9e00bc6e340012a03796.mockapi.io/clients')
  .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
    this.clients = data;
    this.chRef.detectChanges();

    const table: any = $('table'); // we have the jquery obj here
    this.dataTable = table.DataTable(); // error here
  });
```

}

====

3. In the network tab of chrome, I see the jquery version (3.3.1) is loaded correctly with datatable 1.10.19 (as expected). **Note: Liferay 7.1 loads jquery 3.3.1 internally too and as per the network tab its loaded way before my jquery version is loaded.**

Parts of package.json for reference:

```
    "dependencies": {
       "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
       "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.14",
       "@types/datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.0",
       "@types/datatables.net-colreorder": "^1.4.0",
       "@types/datatables.net-select": "^1.2.4",
       ..
       "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
       "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.19",
       "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.5.4",
       "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.5.4",
       "datatables.net-colreorder": "^1.5.1",
       "datatables.net-colreorder-bs4": "^1.5.1",
       "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.3",
       "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.3",
       "datatables.net-select": "^1.2.7",
       "datatables.net-select-bs4": "^1.2.7",
       "datatables.responsive.typings": "^1.0.3",
       "jquery": "^3.3.1",
     }
    "devDependencies": {
       ..
       "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
       "typescript": "2.4.2",
       "liferay-npm-bundler": "^2.0.0",
       ..
     }
```

I am stuck here, as I tried a lot of different approaches but none worked.

Has anyone successfully implemented the combination (angular + jquery datatable + liferay 7.1)?

Any suggestion or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Note: As this is a Liferay based solution I do not have an option to share the sample to see my issue. But I would be able to test any suggestion if required. The standalone version is just same as that in the repo mentioned above and the same works as shown here:

https://liorchamla.github.io/angular-datatables-from-scratch/

Answer (score 1):

First, try to remove your version of jQuery so that there is only one jQuery loaded (the Liferay 7.1 one).

Second, in your javascript, pass the jQuery instance to it when loading the datatable library:

`require( 'datatables.net-bs4' )( window, jQuery );`